# Local Linux repository

Tags: linux, updates, repository

Just like how you can setup a WSUS (Windows Server Update Services), can you also setup a local Linux based repo?

I do a lot of Linux servers and would like to push the updates to my servers locally so that they are faster and more secure.

EDIT: The main OS is CentOS or RHEL.

The idea is to have ALL the servers in our network call our update server and pull updates and packages from it.

Comment: It's not possible to provide complete answer unless we know what Linux distro you're using.

Comment: If you're using **yum**, [Caching remote data for multiple computers](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumMultipleMachineCaching) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. While it may not be that similar to WSUS, it is possible to set up local Linux repositories.
The exact procedure varies with the distribution you are trying to cover.

Here are the guides for a couple common distributions:

- [CentOS](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/CreateLocalMirror)
- [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Local_Mirror)
- [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository)
- [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror)